# Помогите исправить ошибку с SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Когда пытаюсь загрузить данные в базу

```
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO trips (trip_id, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", 
             [(i, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km)])
```

выдает ошибку: **ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.**

Ошибка в том, что внутри списка кортеж. Если убрать круглые скобки, то все работает. Вероятно, если убрать квадратные, а круглые оставить - тоже будет работать. Либо список, либо кортеж. Так получается отправляются некорректные данные. И да, лучше не использовать '%s'

Работающий вариант:

```
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO trips (trip_id, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
             [i, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO trips (trip_id, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (i, taxi_id, day_type, missing_data, start_ts, start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, nb_points, dist_km))
```

Попробуйте вот так,использовать %s при работе с бд небезопасно,функция execute, принимает кортеж и подставляет значения вместо вопросительных знаков в тело запроса